# How can I test whether my 3 wire electric motor is broken?

Tags: motor, test

I have a motor that I'm trying to work out if it's faulty or not. The motor make and model is EMC RB2C-190-060 K010 (photos below) -

230V
~ 50/60 Hz
2μF-450V
65/90W
0.3/0.4A

The motor has four wires coming off it: brown, black, blue, yellow&green. I have tested the resistance between them with a multimeter as follows:

- Blue to black = 1 (on all Ω settings)
- Blue to brown = 1 (on all Ω settings)
- Black to brown = 380 (on 2000 Ω setting)
- Blue/black/brown to yellow&green = 1 (on all Ω settings)

Is this enough information to tell? I'm happy to test by wiring it up to power, but I'm not sure what the capacitor to use and how to wire in the capacitor. Any help appreciated, thanks.[image]

Comment: the readings you presented make no sense ... you may have a defective multimeter ... black to brown should be 2, if black-blue and blue-brown are both 1

Comment: Anything to Yellow/Green should be infinity not 1 ... unless you mean (1---) which is overrange. Then are the other readings really 1, or overrange too?

Comment: I believe that you may be seeing flashing "1" on a digital ohmmeter. That would mean infinity or op1n circuit. That is the proper reading for the yellow & green, meaning that no windings are grounded. On the others, it indicates no connection where there should be a connection. My guess is that an internal thermal fuse has opened because the motor overheated. It may be possible to change that, but it would probably be difficult and would not fix whatever made the motor overheat.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I think the "1" on my multimeter is infinity which sounds like the motor is faulty as I suspected. I wanted to be more sure before I spend £140 on a new one. The motor was installed in 2009 when my flat was built so I'm guessing it could be age.